# mysql.sock and rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, mysql.sock

This is not necessarily a programming question, but this issue is definitely blocking development (not to mention that there are thousands of questions on stackoverflow related to this, but none that I can see that address the issue I'm dealing with).

I've been working with rails and mysql for several months. At the time I did the install, all was fine, and up until about a week ago, I was able to run migrations, phpmyadmin, etc. without any problems.

Today, I was trying to create a new application (following the railscast 323). I also use Rubymine for an IDE.

I created the project using the IDE, project.new and created a new Rails application. I then proceeded created the scaffolding along with a migration file. I then did rake db:create and it seems as if the DB was created. When I tried doing rake db:migrate, I got the following error:

'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)'

I checked my config/database.yml (the file was created by the IDE) and it does have

socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

Additional information:

There is a /usr/local/var/mysql/store_development directory, so it seems as if the database was created.

I can go to /localhost/phpmyadmin, but my root password is not accepted (I did not change the root password)

I have not re-installed mysql
I have not updated mysql

/tmp/mysql.sock no longer exists
/usr/var/mysql/mysql.sock does not exist

Any ideas?

Comment: I tried /usr/local/bin/mysqld stop but it was going through a loop (could not even stop it by doing control-c)

Comment: Have you tried `$ ps aux |grep mysql`? You will see what mysql processes are running. It seems like your server is down as willyglynn wrote.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure mysqld is running.
If yes, try this:

```
ln -sf $(locate mysql.sock) /tmp
```